# MySQL: REGEXP statement works incorrect

Tags: sql, mysql, regex

Why this `SELECT "»" REGEXP "^[-а-я]*$"` SQL statement returns 1 (true). Symbol "»" doesn't match this regular expression.

In other case, it works correctly with symbol "«":
`BINARY` after `REGEXP` doesn't resolve problem

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly a guess but character ranges can be problematic in combination with localization as described in https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2023/04/06/tips-handling-rational-ranges-in-regular-expressions

According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/regexp.html) it uses the ICU library to handle regular expressions. And this one happens to have an interesting example which might be working for you.

```
^[\p{Letter}&&\p{script=cyrillic}]$
```

(I'm not sure if it includes upper case letters)

> Logical AND or intersection. Match the set of all Cyrillic letters.

https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html

Apart from that you can try to explicit list all characters explicit instead of using a range.

Answer (score 0):

5.7 says "The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multibyte safe and may produce unexpected results"

8.0 says "MySQL implements regular expression support using International Components for Unicode (ICU), which provides full Unicode support and is multibyte safe. (Prior to MySQL 8.0.4, MySQL used Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions, which operates in byte-wise fashion and is not multibyte safe." -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

So...  Upgrade your MySQL so you can use REGEXP with Cyrillic.